# Google Cloud Endpoints Security (OAuth2) and custom User schema

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm reading the Google Cloud Endpoints docs related to OAuth2 Security.
I assume this kind of security is against Google accounts.

Is there any support to have a custom User schema to authenticate against?

What I would like is to have client JS application which uses Google Cloud Endpoints but authenticate against local storage (App Engine) of users.

Is Google Clound Endpoints suitable for this or do I need to write my own Security mechanism?

Comment: You need to write your own.

Comment: Were you able to come up with a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of OAuth is:

An end point is implemented by a provider, so when an application such as yourself, authenticates a user such as myself, it returns a result.

Now the *problem* is if google's end points can return custom schema.

What you could do is, implement the functions, and change your DNS (`/etc/conf`) so that google's endpoints hit your localhost. In principal this will work, however in practice I am not sure I would do this myself, but perhaps you have your reasons.

So with AppEngine, I imagine there might be a class which overrides/implements this stuff. With the DNS rewrite trick, you should be able to get it to work.

If you do, please write about it, so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth for Cloud Endpoints is Google accounts only. You would have to write your own.

Honestly, just use Google Accounts, user can even sign up for Google accounts with their own email address. In the future they will probably support Open ID with Endpoints as well.